# Serial output shift register indetermination

Tags: verilog

I wrote a parallel-in serial-out shift register, which I present here.

```
module shiftreg32b (clk, reset, shift, carrega, in, regout);
    input clk;
    input reset, shift;
    input carrega;
    input [31:0] in;

    output regout;

    reg [31:0] inreg;

    assign regout = inreg[31];

    always @ (posedge clk)
    begin
        if (reset == 1) inreg <= 32'd0;
            else if (carrega) inreg <= in;
                else if (shift) inreg <= {inreg[30:0], 1'b0};
    end

endmodule
```

The problem I found is that the output for this shift register is always an unknown (`StX`), even when I've set `assign regout = 0;` to be sure. The test is very simple, and everything else is working fine (`inreg` shifts when `shift` is enabled, etc).

Am I using the assign in a wrong way? Can anyone point to the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `assign` is correct.

Since you didn't provide a testbench, my best guess is that you have multiple drivers of `regout`, most likely when you connected the output port up to something else.

Using this minimal testbench, I see `regout` change from X to 0, as expected

```
module tb;

    reg clk;
    reg reset, shift;
    reg carrega;
    reg [31:0] in;
    wire regout;

initial begin
    $monitor($time, " regout=%b", regout);
    $dumpvars;
    clk = 0;
    reset = 1;
    carrega = 0;
    shift =0;
    in=0;
    #50 $finish;
end

always #5 clk = !clk;

shiftreg32b shiftreg32b (clk, reset, shift, carrega, in, regout);

endmodule
```

Prints:

```
                   0 regout=x
                   5 regout=0
```